# Limiting clabel on contour plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour

I am trying to plot a function using the `contour()` function of `matplotlib.pyplot`. I've tried to add `clabel` to the plot but don't want labels to be added for every level, only the first few. From various demos and the documentation I got to the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def f(x1, x2):
    return (x2 - x1)**4 + 8 * x2 * x1 - x1 + x2 + 3

x1 = np.linspace(-2,2,1000)
x2 = np.linspace(-2,2,1000)

X1, X2 = np.meshgrid(x1, x2)
F = f(X1, X2)
F = np.clip(F, a_min=None, a_max=50)

contours = plt.contour(X1, X2, F, 50, cmap="rainbow")
print(contours.levels)
plt.clabel(contours, contours.levels[0:8], inline=True, fontsize=10, fmt="f = %1.1f", use_clabeltext=True)

plt.title('Q3a Solution')
plt.xlabel('x1')
plt.ylabel('x2')


plt.show()
```

The code works when run in matplotlib version 2.1.2 however running the same code in version 3.0.0 gets the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Tutorial1.py", line 16, in <module>
    plt.clabel(contours, contours.levels[0:8], inline=True, fontsize=10, fmt="f = %1.1f", use_clabeltext=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2496, in clabel
    return gca().clabel(CS=CS, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: clabel() got multiple values for argument 'CS'
```

I've looked all over but can't work out if the usage of the `clabel` has changed, or if this is a bug...

Comment: The [contour label demo](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/contour_label_demo.html) displays the same error message, so a bug is more likely.

Comment: @Mr.T It also helps to always look at the example from the version that is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug in matplotlib 3.0.0, which is now [fixed](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/12293). It'll be available with the upcoming 3.0.1 release.

Note that this is a `pyplot`-only error. It does not occur when using the object oriented methods. 
It is hence also not present in the  [contour label example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/contour_label_demo.html). Please refer to that example in the meantime.

The easiest fix here is to use the `axes`' methods instead of pyplot, i.e. `plt.gca().clabel` instead of `plt.clabel`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def f(x1, x2):
    return (x2 - x1)**4 + 8 * x2 * x1 - x1 + x2 + 3

x1 = np.linspace(-2,2,1000)
x2 = np.linspace(-2,2,1000)

X1, X2 = np.meshgrid(x1, x2)
F = f(X1, X2)
F = np.clip(F, a_min=None, a_max=50)

contours = plt.gca().contour(X1, X2, F, 50, cmap="rainbow")
print(contours.levels)
plt.gca().clabel(contours, contours.levels[0:8], inline=True, fontsize=10, 
                 fmt="f = %1.1f", use_clabeltext=True)

plt.title('Q3a Solution')
plt.xlabel('x1')
plt.ylabel('x2')


plt.show()
```